# Flutter Setting Default ItemCount on ListView Builder

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to build some input fields with ListView Builder and set the default built fields to 3 then add to the number using the floatActionButtion to generate more fields.

But the 3 default fields i set ain't showing up and I couldn't understand what is happening.

Here is my code.

```
int newSULength = 3;

new Expanded(
              child: new Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: new ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return buildfields(index);
                  },
                  itemCount: newSULength,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                ),
              ),
            )
floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            newSULength++;
          });
        },
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      )
```

Below is the field am trying to Build.

```
    Widget buildfields(int index) {
    return new Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          _deleteMode ? deleteButton(index) : null,
          Container(
            width: 110.0,
            child: TextFormField(
              onSaved: (String value) {
                setState(() {
                  _course = value;
                });
              },
              initialValue: 'GNS101',
              inputFormatters: [
                new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),
              ],
              validator: (val) {
                return val.isEmpty ? "Enter Course Code" : null;
              },
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 5.0, 20.0, 8.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new DropdownButton<num>(
              onChanged: (num value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedGrade[index] = value;
                });
              },
              hint: new Text('Grade Point'),
              value: selectedGrade[index],
              items: <num>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((num value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<num>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value.toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new DropdownButton<num>(
              onChanged: (num value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedUnit[index] = value;
                });
              },
              hint: new Text('Course Unit'),
              value: selectedUnit[index],
              items: <num>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((num value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<num>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value.toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ].where(notNull).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**UPDATE:** I discover that my problem is declaring `selectedUnit` and `selectedGrade` as List.

```
List<num> selectedUnit = [];
List<num> selectedGrade = [];
```

i tried using `selectedUnit` and `selectedGrade` as map and it works.

```
var selectedUnit = {};
var selectedGrade = {};
```

But i need to check if the list contains a certain value using `selectedUnit.contain()` and `selectedUnit.add()` and these are not available in Map.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work for you. I'm unsure of the exact problem. There were a few things I had to fill in with your code to get it to build. Review your `notNull` logic because that can return an empty `List`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  int newSULength = 3;
  var selectedUnit = [0, 0, 0];
  var selectedGrade = [0, 0, 0];
  var _course = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return buildfields(index);
                },
                itemCount: newSULength,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            newSULength++;
            selectedUnit.add(0);
            selectedGrade.add(0);
          });
        },
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildfields(int index) {
    return new Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 110.0,
            child: TextFormField(
              onSaved: (String value) {
                setState(() {
                  _course = value;
                });
              },
              initialValue: 'GNS101',
              inputFormatters: [
//                new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),
              ],
              validator: (val) {
                return val.isEmpty ? "Enter Course Code" : null;
              },
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 5.0, 20.0, 8.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new DropdownButton<num>(
              onChanged: (num value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedGrade[index] = value;
                });
              },
              hint: new Text('Grade Point'),
              value: selectedGrade[index] != 0 ? selectedGrade[index] : null,
              items: <num>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((num value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<num>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value.toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new DropdownButton<num>(
              onChanged: (num value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedUnit[index] = value;
                });
              },
              hint: new Text('Course Unit'),
              value: selectedUnit[index] != 0 ? selectedUnit[index] : null,
              items: <num>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((num value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<num>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value.toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ].where((value) => value != null).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to keep working with `List`s to store values, initialize your `List` member variables with placeholder values. The number of values stored in your `List` member variables must equal the number of elements in your `ListView`. Update your `DropDownButton`'s `value` param to check for the placeholder and return `null` if found. In your FAB's `onPressed`, make sure to add new placeholder values for your new element. `Map`s or proper models would both be better/future alternatives.

Comment: Thank you, I've spotted where the issue is. Kindly check as i've updated my post. Please help.

Comment: If it's a simple `bool` check then you can access the `Map`'s values with `selectedUnit.values.contains(someValue)`. You're using a builder so the indices returned work well with a `Map`. You can create a new key/value pair manually if you want with `selectedUnit['10'] = 1` -- just substitute it with the next valid key if that's what you want to do. It looks like each element is related to a course so unique keys would seem to work better instead of two `List`s with a series of numbers.